# php echo table not working

Tags: php

i been trying to solve this problem for a few hours but still no progress. Want to Echo out my database result onto a table created in my html however it just pop out on the side of the window. Please advice something i can do. Thank you.
[image]
PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

    include 'dbh.php';
    $uid =$_POST['name1'];
    $nric = $_POST['nric1'];
    $number = $_POST['number1'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = '$uid' OR nric = '$nric' OR contact = '$number' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "No result is found! ";
    }
    else
    {

        echo "result found";
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['no']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['surname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['nric']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['contact']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['gender']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['address']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
    }

}
```

Inside my form method.

```
      <!-- Search function aboutus about us website -->

      <form method="post" action="" >

      <div class="panel" id="aboutus">

      <h1>About Us</h1>

      <!-- end of header -->
                <input type="text" name="nric1" 
      placeholder="NRIC"><br> <input type="text" name="name1" 
      placeholder="Name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="number1" placeholder="Details Number"><br>
     <table width = "300" border = "1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
     <tr>
     <th>No</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Surname</th>
     <th>Nric</th>
     <th>Contact</th>
     <th>Gender</th>
     <th>Email</th> 
     <th>Address</th>
     <th>Data</th>
     <tr>
     </table>
     <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does that,you need to echo it in the proper place,inside the HTML.Assuming the you also have the HTML inisde the same php page

```
<form method="post" action="" >

      <div class="panel" id="aboutus">

      <h1>About Us</h1>

      <!-- end of header -->
                <input type="text" name="nric1" 
      placeholder="NRIC"><br> <input type="text" name="name1" 
      placeholder="Name"><br>
    <input type="text" name="number1" placeholder="Details Number"><br>
     <table width = "300" border = "1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
     <tr>
     <th>No</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Surname</th>
     <th>Nric</th>
     <th>Contact</th>
     <th>Gender</th>
     <th>Email</th> 
     <th>Address</th>
     <th>Data</th>
     <tr>
<?php  ...else{
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['no']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['surname']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['nric']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['contact']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['gender']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['address']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
?>


     </table>
     <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
    </form>
```